# Aeroflot Bonus Card + Miles

Tags: air-travel, aeroflot, miles-and-more

I recently joined the Aeroflot Bonus programme by using a temporary card that I found in the Aeroflot magazine. At first I got 500 miles, then, I redeemed a flight and earned 1150 miles. I read that I will get a plastic membership card once I have acquired 2000 miles on my account.

Does that mean that I cannot travel somewhere close with the 1650 miles I have on my bonus account?
Could you tell about your experiences (if you have had any) and what you have understood from this programme?
After I get the plastic card, will the 2000 miles remain, or will I have to re-collect them?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't travel anywhere with only 1650 miles.  For instance, a one-way ticket from Moscow to St. Petersburg costs 15000 miles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been a member of Aeroflot Bonus for close to 10 years now and I must admit that they have some of the most "expensive" redemption rules.  A return (round-trip) travel between Moscow and London cost 30,000 miles, for example.  By comparison, the old BMI (rest in peace) only required about 9,000 miles for the same trip.

You can view how many are required for a trip using their [mileage redemption calculator](http://www.aeroflot.ru/cms/en/calculator_awards).

Comment: Not only the miles-price matters but also how many miles you get for flights. 9,000 miles are "cheaper" than 30,000, right, but if you have to travel twice as much to collect them it's not so advantageous.